# Splitting the record using the delimiter

Tags: perl, split

I am splitting the record using the delimiter '|'. Encounter a scenario where pipe symbol(delimiter) is preceded by escape sequence,in that case pipe symbol couldn't be consider as a delimiter. How do i resolve it using split?
Posted below the sample piece of code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $id = 'Hi|Hello\|Sir';
my @code = split(/\|/,$id);

print $code[1]."\n";
```

The expected output for the above program is "**Hello\|Sir**" but the actual output is "**Hello**".How do i handle the delimiter preceded by escape sequence using split.

Thank You

Comment: You can't use `split`.

Comment: you can use `split(/[^\\]\|/,$id)`  but it gets ugly if you want to cover all cases

Comment: @perreal, No, `$code[0]` would be `H` instead of `Hi`, and it would fail to handle `"Hi|Hello\\\|Sir"`

Comment: @ikegami, `split(/(?<!\\)\|/,$id)`? I mean I think it is possible.

Comment: @perreal, I meant `"Hi|Hello\\\\|Sir"` earlier. Both of your solutions fail to handle `"Hi|Hello\\\\|Sir"`.

Comment: yes, that what I'm saying. my question is, is it impossible to handle escaped escapes?

Comment: @perreal, See my first comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `split`, but `Text::CSV_XS` can parse this format.

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $parser = Text::CSV_XS->new({
   sep_char    => '|',
   escape_char => '\\',
   quote_char  => undef,
   auto_diag   => 2,
   binary      => 1,
});

$parser->parse('Hi|Hello\|Sir');
my @fields = $parser->fields();
print("$fields[1]\n");             # Hello|Sir
```

Comment: You can indeed use split. Why not? See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a negative-assertion look-behind like this:

```
my @code = split(/(?<!\\)\|/,$id,-1);
```

Note, I added -1 as a param to split just in case trailing empty strings between delimiters are significant in your data.

The stuff in any '(?...)' is not captured and the "`<!`" means look at the previous character and fail if it matches.  Thus the pattern will not match if a bar is preceded by a backslash.

Comment: Fails to handle `Hi|Hello\\|Sir` (the string returned by `"Hi|Hello\\\\|Sir"`).

Comment: `perl -e 'my $id = q(Hi|Hello\|Sir);my @code = split(/(?<\!\\)\|/,$id,-1);print $code[1]."\n";'
Hello\|Sir`

Comment: That's not the string it fails for.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this expression in your split:

```
my @code = split(/(?<!\\{1})\|/,$id);
```

Similar to @hepcat72 's 
Which will only split if the preceding character before the pipe is NOT a slash, answer but this one will only split if there is 1 preceding slash

This will split `Hi|Hello\|Sir` into an array of `Hi`, and `Hello\|Sir`

This will also split  `"Hi|Hello\\\\|Sir"` into an array of `Hi`, and `Hello\\|Sir`

Comment: This is identical to hepcat72's solution. (Actually, you made it worse by removing the `-1`.) Like you said, this fails to handle `"Hi|Hello\\\\|Sir"`. That should return three fields.

Comment: what should the output be for that?  then since you double quote it, aren't the escaped slashes turning into single slashes?

Comment: No, `"Hi|Hello\\\\|Sir"` produces the string `Hi|Hello\\|Sir`. The first `\ ` in the string escapes the second `\ `, so the `|` isn't escaped, so you should split on it.